# I installed another SMS application, now I get notified twice

Tags: 2.2-froyo, sms, notifications, handcent-sms

I have a Google Nexus One with Android 2.2. I didn't like the default SMS-application so I installed Handcent-SMS. Now when I get an SMS, I get notified twice. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can turn off notification in your stock Messaging application by going into the settings dialog  (Menu button -> Settings) and unchecking Notifications

Comment: Beat me to it, eh?

Answer (score 6):

The clearest answer I've seen is here: http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-applications/8328-how-guide-disable-double-notifications-when-using-handcent-sms.html

Quoting:

1. Open the "messaging" from the app drawer
2. Push the "menu" button(the 2nd button from left on the bottom of your Droid
3. Click SETTINGS
4. Scroll down and UNCHECK "Notifications"
5. To futher disable the mssaging app you can UNCHECK " Auto-Retrieve"(this prevents the "Messaging" App from even downloading messages.
6. Exit the app. Rejoice. Live long and Prosper. Yay!

Comment: Did not know about Auto-Retrieve. Thought that was what enabled all apps to get the sms. Oy vei.

Answer (score 2):

Open the default messaging application, click the menu button and then Settings. Scroll down and disable **Notifications**.